# World War II MOD for Rise of Nations

Tags: mods, rise-of-nations

Does anyone know if any WWII MODs exist for Rise of Nations or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one: http://ron.heavengames.com/downloads/showfile.php?fileid=815

And another: http://www.moddb.com/mods/world-war-2 (Thrones and Patriots)

So they exist but I haven't tested any of them. The first one seems to have issues with the expansion and the second one may not be finished nor supported. Other than that there are few and far between.